# Duplicate calendar events in Outlook 2011

Tags: ms-office, script

Does someone have a script to merge or delete Outlook 2011 duplicate calendar entries?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to achieve, what method you have tried, and what kind of scripts are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If your Outlook client is not crashing when you select calendars, there is a method in the UI to remove blocks of duplicate or outdated events. I can't find the link to give credit, but here is the process:

1. create a new calendar categorization, call it 'delete' or something.
2. go to calendars view, in **list** view not grid.
3. Cmd-Shift-F 'Advanced Find'
4. Select 'All Events' button
5. Select search option 'Date Created' = 'Any Date', or use the criteria to identify your targeted events. Select contiguous blocks by clicking one, and Shift-Click another.
6. Apply your 'delete' categorization via drag/drop or right-click select 'delete'
7. Select File/Export...

   - Outlook for Mac Data File
   - Items in the category: 'delete'
   - Next
   - 'Yes, delete items after they are exported'
   - uncheck the box because you definitely want to delete all items in this category.
8. Finish

The genius of this method is it avoids the disastrous 'prompt for delete for each event' cycle.

Sorry its not a script, I would prefer that as well but I could not find one.